# Java 2D NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, import, jframe, 2d

Recently I've started coding some Java 2D.

I made this:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {
         Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D) comp;
         Font fontx = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 5);
         comp2D.setFont(fontx);
         comp2D.drawString("Hello World!", 5, 50);
}
```

I did import JFrame and java.awt.*, but there's still a problem.

When I run it, I get this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at game.Game.paintComponent(Game.java:41) - comp2D.setFont(fontx); - Sets Font
    at game.Game.next(Game.java:36) - paintComponent(null); - calls the paintComponent public void from the next() public void
    at game.Game.main(Game.java:26) - next.next(); - calls a public void called "next" using an object called "next" (this public void throws InterruptedException)
Java Result: 1
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: As with any NPE the key piece of information is the line that throws the exception. So, which line throws your NPE (NullPointerException)?

Comment: How can I solve it? 1. debug your code or 2. post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilabel generated a.m. exception

Comment: Updated OP with specific lines. Please check it again.

Comment: do you call paintComponent manualy? sounds like you did something wrong with paintComponent method.

Comment: I call it with "paintComponent(null);" from the next() public void.

Comment: You should use `repaint()` method to use `paintComponent`

Answer (score 4):

You state:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at game.Game.paintComponent(Game.java:41) -  
    comp2D.setFont(fontx); - Sets Font
```

This means that comp2D is null and you're trying to call a method on a null variable.

```
at game.Game.next(Game.java:36) - paintComponent(null); 
     - calls the paintComponent public void from the next() public void
```

This means that you're calling paintComponent directly and passing in null!

So you're calling paintComponent **directly** and passing in null! It should come as no surprise that the Graphics object is null and will throw a NPE if you try to call methods on it.

Solution:

- You almost *never* call paintComponent directly.
- Instead have the JVM call it when you call repaint(). The JVM will pass in a valid Graphics object.
- Most important -- read the [painting with Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). You can't guess at this stuff and expect it to work.
- Be sure that your paintComponent method is held within a JPanel or other JComponent derived component.
- Be sure that your override is valid by using the `@Override` annotation for paintComponent.
- Don't neglect to call the `super.paintComponent(...)` method within your override.
- For example, have your other method change a class field, say have it change a String field called text, then call `repaint()`, and then have your `paintComponent(...)` method use the text field for the text to print in the JPanel. This is just an example. You can change any of the drawing component's fields, and then use them inside of `paintComponent(...)`.

Comment: I'm not guessing, I actually copied it from a book I'm learning from.

How am I supposed to call the public void paintComponent() then?

I have to call it from another public void...

Comment: @BarSharabani: your book actually has you calling `paintComponent(null)`? Really? If so get rid of that book, and instead start with the tutorials that I've linked to. And no, if you're coding correctly, you in fact do not have to call it from another method. Seriously. You change the state of your class, call repaint() and let the JVM call the method. Please read the tutorial link that I've provided. And again, get rid of your book as it's worthless if it is making this recommendation of calling the method directly.

Comment: Nope, it's something that NetBeans suggested to do, because when I tried to do paintComponent() it didn't work. It didn't show an error when I added the null. I'm specifically new to this subject but not to Java.

Comment: OK, Thank you, I'll use the tutorials you've linked to.

Comment: @BarSharabani: Please see the new point in my Solution list for an example of "changing the class's state".